# how to match variable string to json response object

Tags: angularjs, json, angular

How to match `string` variable of `var apiMatch = '/api/Customer'` to the JSON response object comes from the API call

JSON Object looks like the image below

[image]

I thought it'd be straightforward to do something like

```
if(data.paths == apiMatch ) {
  // Do something here when its matched
  console.log('its matched');
} else {
   console.log('Nothing');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear. Are you trying to get the URL from the address bar?

If so, you can try [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

Comment: Not trying to get the URL, I'm trying to match the url parameter value of `apiPath=""` which is `/api/Customer` to my JSON response object which shows in the image above.

Comment: Reword my question.